# One finger momentum scrolling in iOS in overflowing div

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, webkit

I have a webpage with two side by side overflowing divs that split the screen, similar to gmail the iPad.  This works fine on desktop versions of WebKit, but is basically broken on iPhone / iPad because scrolling requires two fingers and lacks any momentum.

What is the best way to implement two scrolling areas for the iPad, similar to gmail, the maintain the standard iOS scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [SproutCore Touch](http://blog.sproutcore.com/introducing-sproutcore-touch/).